# Subclipse RAD 7 cannot compare JS

Tags: subclipse, ibm-rad

I cant seem to compare two JS files (one edited locally and the latest version from the repository when doing Team Synch or Compare With) using Subversion in IBM RAD 7. I have used Subclipse as a plugin version 1.6.8.

I have totally downgraded to Subclipse 1.6.5 because my team mate's IDE (also RAD 7) is working fine on this subclipse version when comparing JS files.

I have also looked up and seems we have both the same version of RAD 7.

Frantically looked for solutions on the net and found nothing.

Sorry if this is the place to look for support. I was attempting to upgrade my RAD but darn the fix packs are so huge even for a little fixes (other fixes I mean)(shoo IBM).

Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant find the workaround so I just patiently downloaded the updates from IBM *sigh*.
Updating to RAD 7.5.5 fixes the problem

Comment: this is still a problem, using Version: 7.5.5.5 iFix1
Build ID: RADO7555iFix1-I20120913_1613

Comment: @slattman - what I have found out (though not using 7.5.5.5) is to prior to commit, where you can enter the comments - you can double click the js and it can compare.